# Force Google Maps API not to autocorrect typed location when geocoding

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm dealing with a problem: when entering a German city name with "u" the API returns the coordinates of a city with "ü" (probably because it is bigger).

How can I force the API to treat entered text as-is? (Using quotation marks doesn't change a thing)

I guess that Region Biasing or any other filtering method won't do any good because the results are restricted to whole Germany and both of the cities are within this range.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such option(I guess this is not a kind of "autocorrection", depending on the charset for databases U and Ü are equal ). Do you only need to find cities?

Comment: @Dr.Molle yes, only cities

Answer (score 1):

As commented, there is no implemented option to avoid this(although it would be a desirable feature).

**Possible solution:**
create your own database of cities. You may e.g. use the data of OSM, the complete dataset for germany may be downloaded at http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html

Use a `utf8`-charset for the table, when  you search for cities within the database use a collation of `utf8_bin` , and you'll get only exact matches.